# What is the title of the head of a steering committee?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am leading a steering committee of a community conference. As a part of the job, I am emailing sponsors and partners with details about the event.

> My name is Adam Matan, and I am **?** of the steering committee...

What is the title of such a person? I have Googled it, but found inconclusive results. Should it be `chair`, `chairperson` or `head`?

Answer (score 3):

The head of any kind of committee is usually called the "chairman" (or the gender-neutral terms "chair" or "chairperson"). From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chairman):

> 1.1 The permanent or long-term president of a committee, company, or other organization.

I don't think there's anything special about a steering committee that suggests any different term would be appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Chairman is the usual title. And madam chairman is the form of address to the chairman if female.

Comment: [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=madam+chairman%2Cchairwoman&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmadam%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchairwoman%3B%2Cc0) seems to suggest _chairwoman_ is used a lot more than _madam chairman_.

Comment: @JJJ *Madam chairman* is the manner of address, not the title of the position, the counterpart of *mister chairman*.

Comment: @choster You're right, however, empirically speaking [it seems that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=madam+chairman%2Cmister+chairman&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmadam%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmister%20chairman%3B%2Cc0) of those two addresses the female version is more common. Maybe the _mister_ part is sometimes left out when addressing a male chairman?

Comment: @JJJ NGrams is [case-sensitive](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=madam+chairman%2CMadam+Chairman%2CMister+Chairman%2CMr+Chairman%2Cmister+chairman&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: @choster Sorry, I meant to show [this case-insensitive one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=madam+chairman%2Cmister+chairman&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmadam%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMadam%20Chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmadam%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMadam%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmister%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMister%20Chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmister%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMister%20chairman%3B%2Cc0) (the female version seems even more common compared to the male version here).

Comment: @JJJ Again, the main point is that the OP asks for a title, not the address, which only introduces confusion because of the lack of explanation. But to address that point, all these phrases have very low prevalence, and so are prone to corpus and statistical error, but surely [consider other variations](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=madam+chairman%2Cmister+chairman%2Cmr+chairman%2Cmadam+chairwoman%2Cmr+chair%2Cmister+chair%2Cmr+chairperson%2Cmister+chairperson%2Cmadam+chair&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) before drawing a conclusion.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.